# CDH upgrade from 5.1 to 5.3

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

After I finished all distribution, activation steps on manager website,
I got the error as below when I restart the cluster:

```
2016-07-14 14:51:12,335 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@UT190320.shis.uth.tmc.edu:50070
2016-07-14 14:51:12,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2016-07-14 14:51:12,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2016-07-14 14:51:12,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2016-07-14 14:51:12,436 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: 
File system image contains an old layout version -55.
An upgrade to version -59 is required.
Please restart NameNode with the "-rollingUpgrade started" option if a rolling upgrade is already started; or restart NameNode with the "-upgrade" option to start a new upgrade.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1534)
2016-07-14 14:51:12,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the upgrade as suggested error messages. It is not clear what exactly you did but I suggest you follow the documentation at http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_earlier_cdh5_upgrade.html

`sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode upgrade` is possibly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, when I run the command, it shows "hadoop-hdfs-namenode: unrecognized service", and I cannot find any service in /etc/init.d/, do you know where I can find such service?

Comment: when I follow the upgrade guideline, when I was trying to stop service using " $ for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-*` ; do sudo service $x stop ; done", it returned "the file cannot be found ", do you have any idea on it?